# Create an AST interactively with javafx

Tags: java, javafx, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

As referred to the title, I want to create an AST interactively with a certain grammar.
But I don't have any idea on how to do it...
So my question is:

Which technology is available right now in creating and editing an AST with javaFX ?

I couldn't see anything on the internet regarding to this...
I know that Webview does work on JavaFX and probably an internet technology will solve that. But I haven't found anything yet with Webview ...

P.S.: One critic information for this, is that my AST must be created by a click of a mouse and not written by the keyboard (as a traditional IDE).
I'm open in different views, so please feel free to say anything.
Any information for solving this, will be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: "Create AST by click of mouse"?  So clicking a button "Parse file" is valid or not as a solution?   Or do you want to construct the tree piecemeal through a GUI?

Comment: I want to create the tree through a GUI basically but he needs to follow some rules of the grammar for creating it correctly ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is you want is called a [structure editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_editor).

Such an editor knows the grammar of the language you want to work with,
and works with an AST for program rather than text.  What you see in the Editor window is a *rendering* of the AST as surface syntax text.  Your cursor selects an AST node by virtue of being nearest to text from that AST node.

Given a cursor/AST node, you can then perform various operations, such as "cut subtree", "paste subtree", "move subtree", or replace a subtree by typing a phrase, causing the editor to parse what you type, often in realtime, to build corresponding tree nodes.

Such editors can usually provide guidance to the process by telling you what syntactic category you are editing (expression, statement, declaration) and usually guesses what you should type next if it is known by the grammar.

The most famous one (being essentially first) was called the "Synthesizer Generator".   I doubt you can get that anymore.  The Wikipedia link provided above has a long list of systems, some of which you can get now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't see the information which i wanted ... gonna see more in the web :/

Comment: What specific information did you want to see?  If you want to know how these tools work, you can always read Thomas Reps PhD thesis that describes the Synthesizer Generator in detail.   If not that, there are lots of papers on the topic all of which contain the words "structure editor".  There aren't books or tutorials on this, in spite of being sexy, they aren't terribly popular in practice.  (There some IDEs that use this idea).

Comment: Well, I wanted to check if there was anything available with "structure editor" in Java. But i see that every topics who refers to that are really old... so...
And i really liked one design ( http://www.programtree.com/editwind.htm ) which I want more or less implement the same with JavaFX !
Otherwise, MPS application from IDEA is not what I'm looking for..

Comment: The tech papers are old because the idea isn't new and there isn't a lot of "research" continuing now.  Still, they're the papers to read.     What don't you like about MPS?

Comment: Well, if you compare MPS to programtree program, one is going to a click mouse effect and another is going to a keyboard effect..

Comment: So programtree initially looks pretty cute.  I'll bet it is in practice unusable on C code.  It might be usable on C# but it doesn't do Unicode.   A key problem with these tools for real languages is you need a high-fidelity parser to read the source text.

Comment: yeah... probably ! :)